# From range [0,1] to range [-117,117]

Tags: linear-algebra

Do you know the formula to get from a range of values `[0,1]` to a range of values `[-117,117]`?

For example if I had the `0.1` value, I'd like to know the corrisponding of the other range.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The initial range has length $1$, the final one length $334$. Using this observation, dilate and shift:
$$x\mapsto 334x-117.$$

Comment: Can you provide some example? If I want to know the corrisponding value of 0.1 ? What is it?

Comment: $0.5\mapsto 334\cdot 0.5-117=117-117=0$ while
$0.1\mapsto 334\cdot 0.5-117=34-117=-83$. Moving $0.1$ in the original range corresponds to moving by $34$ units in the final range.

Comment: What if the range is from [0,1] to [-117,0] ?

Comment: using the same reasoning you should be able to get the result. Show us your efforts

Comment: If the x is 1 ↦ 334⋅1−117 =  334−117=217 but it should be 177..